# Finding "-" Character in a String in JAVA

Tags: java, string

I have an String "University of Wisconsin–Madison@en"

```
String t = "University of Wisconsin–Madison@en"
```

The problem is that when I do `t.contains("-")` I get false but when I do `t.contains("x")`, where x is any other char in the String except `"-"` I get true.

**Problem**: I need to find `"-"` in the String.

Comment: Are you sure that your string contains a hyphen, and not an en-dash?

Comment: Thas symbol is not "-", it is "–".

Comment: `-` and `–` are different ones.

Comment: I think you are getting confused between "-" and "–". the code is proper to detect hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like, given the extended width, it might be an [en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) rather than the ASCII-range hyphen-minus character.

You should be aware that, in the Unicode world, there are a lot of characters that *look* similar but are in fact different code points.

The dashes are [one group where people often get confused](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html).

If you really want to detect that character you're looking for, you should start with a string that actually *contains* it :-)

However, if your intent is to discover any of the rather large number of dashes (or some subset larger than just the hyphen-minus), you'll need to look for more than one possibility.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, this gets even more complicated when you start considering more general cases because of Unicode combining characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). There are multiple ways of rendering "ü", for example: a single pre-combined character (U+00FC), or two characters: an umlaut combining character (U+0308) and a regular u (U+0075). Unicode is complicated when you get below the surface.